# Open Ubuntu Browser from Terminal

Tags: command-line, browser

Very simple question:

**How do you open the Ubuntu Internet Browser from the Terminal?**

I am running a computer through an X-forwarded session, and need to find the command to open the Ubuntu Browser.  It isn't my default browser, so `sensible-browser` doesn't open it.  I tried:

```
browser
ubuntu-browser
gnome-browser
sensible-browser
brow*
```

They all returned `Command not found,` except `sensible-browser`, which opened chrome.

Comment: Are you talking of the default browser for Ubuntu ?

Comment: @George, depends what you mean.  I'm talking about the Ubuntu Browser, which comes by default with Ubuntu 16.04, but not about the browser that is *set as default.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's actually `webbrowser-app`

```
nano /usr/share/applications/webbrowser-app.desktop
```

The .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Type=Application
Icon=browser
Exec=webbrowser-app %u
Terminal=false
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=webbrowser-app
X-Ubuntu-Single-Instance=true
X-Ubuntu-Default-Department-ID=web-browsers
X-Screenshot=/usr/share/webbrowser-app/screenshot.png
X-Ubuntu-Splash-Color=#FFFFFF
```

Comment: Never knew that existed, an interesting learn for me today.